# if i remove the ".NET framework 4.7" for 4.6.2 target Development

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

※!WARNING! terrible english skill

hello.
i am kind of developer(System Integrator).
now, i join the one project using mfc, .NET

this project's target version is .NET Framework 4.6.2
but, my development pc(win10) is automatically updated(v4.7.x).

so, i wanna remove v4.7 for fit to release PC.
(release PC is cant change .NET version.
release PC is offlinePC, so, they can control .NET version.)

but, i heard remove v4.7 is not recommended solution.
im worry about thing is this.

1) if i remove the ".NET framework 4.7", is that cause of any problem?

2) or guide safely re-install to set 4.6.2 if exist?

Comment: Hi. The question is, do you have a problem that needs solving. Does your program/solution run on your computer? To get Visual Studio to use 4.6 you simply need to install the .NET Targetting pack from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321).

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Thanks for the comment. yes, solution will be run my computer for the test.  I already download 4.6.2ver install file and trying install that. but, install program is answer to me "you already installed Latest version. so, cant install 4.6.2!"

Comment: You target the version that the user of your program needs to have installed.  Not the one you have installed.  It is quite common to intentionally pick a lower version, 4.6.2 is not wrong.  Do **not** remove 4.7 from your machine, that can break other programs, like VS.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the comment. i thought same result(DON'T remove 4.7). i just wanna check other solution. so, i collecting more opinion or answers.i think many users comments will be help a lots to me(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your Target framework directly from your solution

1. Click on the project > then click on properties
2. Click on the dropdown Target framework.
3. Choose the one you need[image]

So you don't need to install or uninstall anything.

Comment: thanks for the answer. actually, i already do this before the write this question. this project is not using internet, and will be running least decade years. so, if someone join this project when many times after, .NET framework will be more update. so, i wanna more opinion or answer how to set same environment for develop or others...

Comment: @JohnSmith Are you using git or something else for version controlling?

Comment: you means, source's version controlling, right? unfortunately, this project is sealed project. so, we using TortoiseSVN. installed in local connected computer.

Comment: when you update the target version, your .csproj file will be updated. It will add something like this "<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>" to the .csproj file. So if all of them are using same source code, you all will have same target framework. @JohnSmith